# Histogram "doubles" the frequency of many values

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram

I have a 1000x1000 2D array and I need to plot a histogram of that values. I've converted it to a  1D array with 1M elements and used the hist function of pyplot.

The result is not the expected, and it seems to be bins dependant:

1. [1000 bins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpeG5.png)
2. [400 bins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXCk6.png)
3. [100 bins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRz0p.png)

There are values that seems doubled or something like that every few bins. Any ideas?

Thanks :D

Edit: The 2D array and the code: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/0c241a47459cadb940ded0cf4ac0155020220404185020/5c31e487e725ed987a416ed7dd1c137d20220404185021/8b4a62

```
ma=np.load("magarray.npy")
mag=ma.flatten()

plt.hist(mag, density=True,bins=400)
plt.xlim(0,25)
plt.xlabel("Value of magnification")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.title("Magnification histogram")
```

Comment: Without seeing a dataset, there's almost nothing we can do.  My guess, based on scant evidence, is that you have rounding issues causing multiple bins to coalesce.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve].

Comment: That's a good point to start from @TimRoberts, thanks. I've added more information to the main post.

Comment: "It seems to be bins dependent" is true: histograms of discrete values are inherently bins dependent

Comment: For discrete values, it helps a lot to set the bin edges exactly at the center of values.  E.g. `bins=np.arange(-0.05, mag.max()+0.1, 0.1)`  (Whenever possible, try not to round values to be put in a histogram)

Comment: There are only 769 distinct values in your 1 million element array.  Doing a 1,000-element histogram is a bit silly.  Why do you think the bins should be monotonically decreasing?  I suspect the graphs accurately reflect your dataset.  In other words, there's nothing wrong here.

Comment: L.ScottJohnson I mean the problem was bin dependant, not the histogram itself...

JohanC I've tried that with no better results. I'll try with no rounding values but I guess it will be the same since the rounding affects in the same way to identical values

@TimRoberts you are right, I didn't noticed that... it has no sense to make more bins than different values. The problem persists with 400 values although. I don't think the bins must be decreasing all the time, what I think is that their behavior should not be related with the number of bins because they change dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is nothing more than an artifact of your data, which is virtually a step function.  This is just aliasing -- your data's frequency beating against the bins frequency.  Do the histogram manually, and you'll see that there's nothing nefarious here.  Here is 400 bins:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.load('magarray.npy').reshape(1000000)
minx = data.min()
maxx = data.max()

def xmap(x):
    return int((x - minx) * len(bins) / maxx)

bins = [0]*400

for v in data:
    bins[xmap(v)] += 1

print(bins)
plt.plot(bins)
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]